# PHP : how to Let preg_match accept a URL/

Tags: php, variables

I'm newbie in PHP, and I use this code to detect if a special url are include in a file :

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'detect_error');
function detect_error(){
    $file_path = locate_template('file.php'); #Get the absolute server path of file
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path); #Store the file contents in a var
    $citation_msg_string = '<a href="http://link.com/">anchor</a>'; #The required string
    if(!preg_match("/$citation_msg_string/", $file_contents))
        exit('Warning : The link are missed in your file'); #Detecter l'ajout de lien dans le fichier
}
```

but i have this error msg :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'
```

if i add a link in this var :

```
$citation_msg_string = '<a href="http://link.com/">anchor</a>';
```

So please, how to let **preg_match** accept URL?

Thanks.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the slashes in your pattern, just use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape them, e.g.

```
if(!preg_match("/" . preg_quote($citation_msg_string, "/") . "/", $file_contents))
                   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Bravo Bravo Bravooooooooo it works like a charm :)
Thanks a lot for your help.